# Table View Frame doesn't edit just after loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, frame

I'm having an issue with my swift code. I'm trying to change table view frame just after loading but it doesn't work...
Here is my code:

```
if lastIndex == 0 {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        var tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame
        tableViewFrame.origin.y += tableViewFrame.size.height/2
        tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height/2
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame
        }, completion: { finished in
            println("Table View state changed!")
    })
}
else if lastIndex == 2 {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        var tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame
        tableViewFrame.origin.y -= tableViewFrame.size.height/2
        tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height/2
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame
        }, completion: { finished in
            println("Table View state changed!")
    })
}
else {
    var tableViewFrame = tableView.frame
    tableViewFrame.origin.y += tableViewFrame.size.height/2
    tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height/2
    tableView.frame = tableViewFrame
    println("Executed")
}
```

When the else condition is true the table view doesn't resize and I dont know why...

Comment: Where did you put this code? In which function?

Comment: this is a custom function `func segmentAction(sender: AnyObject)`. I call this function in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: You should check whether self.tableView.frame is {{0,0},{0,0}}. I think it will be in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @TheFlow_ Call your custom function in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead

Comment: @TheFlow_ Glad to hear it :)